# com.intellij.lang.properties.charset.Native2AsciiCharsetProvider not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I created a project in IDEA based on `gradle`, and I use `spring-boot` to run my project.

When it starts, I found the code `Charset.availabeCharsets()` will throw exception that pointed to:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: 
Provider com.intellij.lang.properties.charset.Native2AsciiCharsetProvider not found.
```

It is strange because I never encountered this.

Does anyone know why this exception thrown and how to fix it? Is it because of some setting incorrect in project or grable file?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and moving the file into the directory?

Comment: Thanks. No, Two problem are: I dont where I can get this file and I dont know why it needs this file which is quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is due to a bug in gradle with its new support Kotlin. Take a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12549#tab=Comments